# SVG files Import in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, react-typescript

I'm building a component in React Typescript and when I try to import svg files, the app doesn't render them.

I've tried all kinds of imports like these below:

```
import { ReactComponent as /*any name*/} from '../../assets/';
const Name = require('../../assets');
import Name from '../../assets/';
```

also tried the custom-ds thing that I saw people suggesting, also didn't work (but I'm not sure I've done it correctly), an all it shows is this
[PNG loaded, SVGs not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBOfe.png)

and this is the code for it

```
import { BackButton, BackIcon, HeaderDiv,
PeriodoTitle, SwitchButton, SwitchDiv, SwitchImg } from "./style";


type header = {
    title: string;
};

export default function PageHeader(
    {title}: header
) {
    return (
        <HeaderDiv>
            <BackButton>
                <BackIcon src={require('../../assets/Back.png')}/>
            </BackButton>

            <SwitchDiv>
                <SwitchButton>
                    <SwitchImg src={require('../../assets/goright.svg')}/>
                </SwitchButton>

                <PeriodoTitle>{title} Período</PeriodoTitle>
                
                <SwitchButton>
                    <SwitchImg src={require('../../assets/goleft.svg')}/>
                </SwitchButton>
            </SwitchDiv>
        </HeaderDiv>
    );

};
```

as you can see the arrow to go back is displayed normally as a png but all svg simply doesn't render, any suggestions ?

Comment: Did you try using single import for svg and passing that to `src`?

Comment: Add image to public folder or static folder in root directory then simply pass the path to your src.
if it is from public directory then like this: <SwitchImg src="/goright.svg"/>
or if it is from static directory then :  <SwitchImg src="/static/goright.svg"/>

Answer (score 1):

If you are using vite for react app. You can use vite plugin called "vite-plugin-svgr"

Install it with

```bash
# yarn
$ yarn add vite-plugin-svgr

# npm
npm i vite-plugin-svgr
```

edit `vite.config.js` file

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite' 
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react' 
import svgr from "vite-plugin-svgr"; 
  
// https://vitejs.dev/config/ 
export default defineConfig({ 
  plugins: [svgr(), react()], 
})
```

And after that you can import any svg image as a react component like that

```
import { ReactComponent as IconMenuClose } from "../assets/images/icon-menu-close.svg";
```

Comment: I saw this problem in other related questions but, unfortunately, I'm not using vite, just big ol npm start

Comment: Take a look at this blog post
https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-svgs-react/

Comment: Thanks for the link, it actually worked, but what I found was that instead of importing it, directly using the whole svg in the component, which makes my code a lot less organized but I'll think on how to minimize it, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this by any chance?

```
import SwitchLeft from '../../assets/goleft.svg'
// ...
<SwitchImg src={SwitchLeft}/>
```

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-import-svgs-in-react-and-vite/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Actually did, it's the third import that I said I tried.

Comment: @IagoCesar from the 3rd line, I can see you're trying to import from a folder, and not importing a specific SVG file within that folder

Comment: @oasido that was just the example leading to the folder but I did specify the whole path in my code